# How do I overwrite a variable in C# with a value of another type?

Tags: python, c#, types, casting

In Python, I was used to doing stuff like this without the compiler complaining:

```
test = "Hello"
test = 1
```

I am now trying to learn C#, but it will not allow me to overwrite variables like that, since they have different types:

```
string test = "Hello";
int test = 3;
```

The above snippet will throw an error:

> Error CS0128  A local variable or function named 'test' is already
> defined in this scope

One possible workaround is to do something like this:

```
string testString = "Hello";
int testInt = 3;
```

But I believe this to be poor practice for two reasons:

- It forces you to have one variable per type, even in cases where you don't need the first type anymore
- It allocates memory to a type which is not needed anymore in the code.

Is there really no clean way to overwrite variables or their types in C#? I have grown quite accustomed to doing this in python and it allows for clean code in my opinion.

Comment: C# is a statically-typed language, and as such, variables have a single type. In practice it's very rare to want to store one type in a variable at one point, and a different type at a different, later, point, so the net result is a large benefit. Also don't worry about a couple of bytes of member (particularly member which doesn't cause a new heap allocation)

Comment: no. there is not. **by design**, since c# is a strongly and statically typed language. that's so if you declare something as a string, you can be certain that there will _never_ be anything in it that's _not_ a string. (which is one of the many reasons why i personally can not stand python.)

Comment: In C# a string remains as a string. You shouldn't want to change this behaviour.

Comment: also, personally, i'd say that reusing one variable name with multiple different types is a big, big, big code smell and should never be done, even if the language allows it. it's rather the opposite of "clean code"

Comment: Even if you _can_ do this in Python, it is not a good idea to do so...

Comment: Agree with all the above. Trying to use one variable for different purposes is a great way to introduce subtle and hard to fix bugs into your code by accident. I would strongly advise against it - even when both purposes involve values of the same type it's still not a good idea. The memory saving you get by doing so is trivial, but the reduction in the testability, readability and maintainability of your code is much more significant

Comment: How about `object`?. `Console.WriteLine(x)` will work with whatever you assign to `object x`. I doubt you can provide a snippet in C# to prove where "overriding" type would be really useful. But  you can at least show python one, this way you may get a better suggestion of how you should achieve the same in C#.

Answer (score 2):

C# is a statically-typed language, which means once you declared a variable, you cannot change its type.

For example, take `int x=12;`. `x` just accepts numeric values; you cannot store string like "osman" in it.

You can use `dynamic` like below:

```
dynamic test = "osman";
test = 2;
test = 3.4;
```

Comment: While you *can* do this, **please don't**, particularly if you're learning the language. `dynamic` is a very niche feature, and you throw away all of the lovely type-safety that C# gives you

Comment: @canton7 I completely agree with you, I just wanted to tell him there is a feature for this.

Comment: Yep, and my comment is directed at OP, telling them not to do this